# Array from recursive promises returns undefined

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, indexeddb

I am using Jake Archibald's indexedDB promise [wrapper](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb).

I have an object store that contains json objects and a separate auto incremented key. When I retrieve the objects i need to also get the key so i can later delete them.

I'm using iterateCursor to recursively step through the cursor so that i can directly add the key and value to an array which i return as a resolved promise.

```
static getThings(){

    return thingsDb.then(db => {
        let keyVals = [];

        const tx = db.transaction('things');
        const unsyncedStore = tx.objectStore('things');

        return unsyncedStore.iterateCursor(cursor => {
            if(!cursor) return Promise.resolve(keyVals);
            console.log(`key: ${cursor.primaryKey}, val: ${cursor.value}`);
            keyVals.push({key: cursor.primaryKey, value: cursor.value});
            cursor.continue();
        });
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });

}
```

however when I call

```
DBHelper.getThings().then(returnedArray=> {
  // do something with returnedArray
})
```

it throws an error saying the returned array is undefined.

Comment: what does the function `unsyncedStore.iterateCursor` return?

Comment: reading the documentation on the page you linked to suggests (I don't know for sure) that perhaps rather than `return unsyncedStore.iterateCursor(cursor => {` ... you just `unsyncedStore.iterateCursor(cursor => {` and after that block `return unsyncedStore.complete;` - or perhaps `return unsyncedStore.complete.then(() => keyVals);`

Comment: @JaromandaX According to the [documentation](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb), It's a wrapper for openCursor that is used to iterate over the cursor using promises and it works identically but takes a callback for the iteration instead of calling .then() on it.

Comment: All I did was look at the code in the example, and it seems `unsyncedStore.complete` is a promise that resolves when the iteration is **complete** - of course, then you'll want to return the array you built up, hence the `.then(() => keyVals)` so the returned promise resolves to `keyVals` - the documentation doesn't mention what `iterateCursor` actually returns, and if it returns undefined, then that's the issue

Comment: @JaromandaX Its my understanding that tx.complete just returns a promise that resolves/rejects based on transaction success, and that if your operation actually returns something you just return that promise

Comment: Looking into the source code, `iterateCursor` has a *typescript* return type of void (i.e. undefined I guess) - so, try the solution I proposed

Comment: `tx.complete just returns a promise` - no, `tx.complete` **is** a promise, that resolves when the transaction completes (or rejects on error) - this is the `promise` you want, because when it resolves, you know the iteration is *complete*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iterateCursor` doesn't return anything (i.e. returns undefined)

You need to return the `promise` available at `unsyncedStore.complete`

But this promise won't resolve to a useful value, so, use `.then` to return the `keyVals`

Also, no point in doing `if(!cursor) return Promise.resolve(keyVals);` since the return value from the `iterateCursor` callback is ignored

```
static getThings() {
    return thingsDb.then(db => {
        let keyVals = [];

        const tx = db.transaction('things');
        const unsyncedStore = tx.objectStore('things');
        // no return here since iterateCursor doesn't return anything useful anyway   
        unsyncedStore.iterateCursor(cursor => {
            if (!cursor) return;
            console.log(`key: ${cursor.primaryKey}, val: ${cursor.value}`);
            keyVals.push({key: cursor.primaryKey, value: cursor.value});
            cursor.continue();
        });
        // return here - complete is a promise that resolves when the iterateCursor completes
        return unsyncedStore.complete.then(() => keyVals);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! I guess my problem was that i was thinking iterateCursor would behave exactly like a regular promise would, When i get a chance I'm going to see about adding that to his documentation.